# Change output_buffering in php.ini but not working

Tags: php, linux, php-ini

I am trying my code like this

```
if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
       $year=$_GET["year"];
}  else {
   if (date("n")>=6) {
       $year = date("Y")+1;
       header('Location: '.$year);
       exit();
   } else {
      $year = date("Y");
  }
}
```

It show error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/2019_7ikeiu/aaaaaa.com/index.php:1) in /home/2019_7ikeiu/aaaaaa.com/index.php on line 9
```

I use this

```
phpinfo();
```

to check php.ini it show `output_buffering 0` and php.ini file located at

```
/etc/php70/php.ini
```

but if I check by SSH with comment

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

it show my php.ini in `/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/etc/php.ini`

I edited my php.ini with `output_buffering = 4096`
but dont know why phpinfo still show `output_buffering 0`

please help me, thank you.

Comment: The clue is in the error - line one of index.php must be generating some output. You can't change the headers after you've started to output the main content of the page

Comment: Can you share the code mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to edit the `php.ini` that is shown in `phpinfo()`, because there are 2 `php.ini`'s, one is for the web server (which is either *apache* or *nginx*) and the `php.ini` that is use in the console.

After you edit the `php.ini`, please already restart your web server so it can load the latest PHP config.